# C# Application freezes at adding the SQLite query results to List<string>

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite

I have a query which returns 66 rows, each of these rows contains a unique_id and I want to save the results in a List so I can use them for further queries. But the code freezes at the line which is supposed to add the rows to the list. I can't find where my problem is! This is My code:

```
public List<string> unique_id;
public List<string> get_unique_id_connection()
    {
        SQLiteConnection m_dbConnection;
        m_dbConnection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=akm.sqlite;version=3;");

        m_dbConnection.Open();
        string sql2 = "SELECT unique_id FROM mos_tbl WHERE region = 10";
        SQLiteCommand command2 = new SQLiteCommand(sql2, m_dbConnection);
        SQLiteDataReader rdr2 = null;
        rdr2 = command2.ExecuteReader();
        while (rdr2.Read())
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < rdr2.FieldCount; i++)
            {
                //MessageBox.Show(rdr2.GetValue(i).ToString());
                unique_id.Add(rdr2.GetValue(i).ToString());//This is where it freezes
            }
        }
        return unique_id;
    }
```

When I uncomment the MessageBox I can see the correct results, so I guess the problem is not the query.

Comment: please elaborate on "the code freezes"

Comment: Do you get any excpetions? try surrounding the sql statement with a try/catch and see what you get.

Comment: Why the `for` loop? You're SELECTing only one field, so why not access it with `rdr.GetValue(0)` directly?

Comment: "*When I uncomment the MessageBox I can see the correct results*" - is this code running on another thread?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure there is no *NullReferenceException* thrown? It looks like there is no `unique_id` list object created while you're adding elements to it.

Comment: Good catch! First line should be `public List<string> unique_id = new List<string>();`

Comment: @James - If this is all the code there is and `unique_id` does not get initialized somewhere else, then this *is* the answer, or at least answer enough to push the OP into the right direction.

Comment: @James: OP says *When I uncomment the MessageBox I can see the correct results*. If this is true, this is the answer.

Comment: @Corak wrong, this is a question & a suggestion - it's not an answer.

Comment: @JaroslawWaliszko my point is, your "answer" should be a comment given how it's been worded. The uninitialized list may well be the problem in this case but instead of asking for more context (which should be done via comments) try suggesting a solution to the problem.

Comment: @James - It seems that you have a very narrow definition of what an answer is. I'd say an answer is a repy to a question that satisfies the intend of the questioner. And this reply *does* lead to a solution of a problem.

Comment: @Corak Thanks guys. First line shoud've been public List<string> unique_id = new List<string>();

Comment: @Corak I doubt that - my point was to me this "answer" could have been worded in such a way that it was a direct answer and not a "is it this?". That is the whole point of the comments facility, to ask the OP questions in order to make sure he/she hasn't done something silly (like they clearly have done in this scenario) or gain more context about the question before actually getting into a full blown answer. Personally I just don't think a question is an answer to a question - even saying that doesn't make sense, regardless the problem has been sourced so it came together in the end :)

Comment: @James - A question can't answer a question? Have you heard about rethorical questions? ;)

Comment: @Corak Nope, I've heard of *rhetorical* questions though :P

Comment: @James - they kind of work the same way, only rethorical questions also have the connotation of making me look stupid. ^_^;